# DateTime.ToString(format) unexpected behavior on different pc

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-4.0

there.
I'm developing a simple interface to get data from SQLServer and i use the function `DateTime.ToString(String)`

The actual code is `DP.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:00")`,
where  DP is a DateTimePicker control.

All works fine while I test it on my own laptop. But when I move the compiled code on another pc, the result is different.
E.g.: It passes from `2013-03-27 22:02` to `2013-03-27 22.02`, replacing the '.' with ':' in the hour.
But this is sufficient to crash my app, because SQLServer generate an invalid date.

What may be the culprit?
Both pc have SQLServer 2008 R2 (and same collation) and .NET Framework 4.0 Client Profile installed.
A difference I have seen is that my SQLServer have the English(United States) language property, while the other have Italian setted, but I should have overcome it with the format string...

Comment: Why are you passing the value to SQL as a *string* at all? Use parameterized SQL and set the parameter value as the DateTime.

Comment: This is my very first time to try this kind of project, and I wanted to start by doing something as simply as write a query.

Comment: Yes, so write a query - with parameters. It's cleaner, isn't open to SQL injection attacks, and doesn't have conversion issues. You're going to have to start using parameters sooner or later - do it right from the start, so you don't get into bad habits.

Comment: I will keep it in mind, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not specifying a culture, so the current culture is being used.  On the other system, "." is used for the time specifier, not ":".

You can [specify a culture explicitly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8tfzyc64.aspx), however, to avoid this:

```
var str = DP.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:00", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

That being said, using a parameterized query and keeping the value as a `DateTime` would be a better habit than passing a date as a string.

Comment: Many thanks, this solves my problem. like I said, I tried to do something simply, writing it in form of query. then I will try different solution.

Comment: I just don't understand why they don't make it universal when you have already specified the string format.

Answer (score 2):

> What may be the culprit?

The culture settings for the user.

Some cultures use a `.`, some `:` for the time separator.

Solution?

Use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` (or a selected `CultureInfo`) to ensure consistency:

```
DP.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:00", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```